# How to send a REST request to Cloud Firestore

Tags: rest, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, postman

I've build an Android app using Firebase, but I'd like to test the performance of the Cloud Firestore using REST requests (through Postman). I've looked up some info on some sites from Firebase, but everytime I send a request, I get a 404 Not Found.

The Authentication I use seems to work, by doing a POST request to 
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=MY_API_KEY I'm able to get a Firebase Id Token.

After that I tried sending a GET request to https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/parent=projects/MY_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/MY_COLLECTION_ID with the token as Authrorization header, but everytime I seem to get 404 Page Not Found.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I wasn't supposed to include  the `parent=` in the URL, I removed it and now it works just fine.